# What is wrong with this powershell script that iterates a List? Foreach-Object -Process { Set-Alias ... }

Tags: c#, powershell

I have got a module that returns a List of LinuxAlias (class I made)

When I try to iterate them to Set-Alias in my session I am having troubles.

Data:
MyModule has the Get-LinuxAliases command.
Get-LinuxAliases command is a binary module that returns a List of LinuxAlias.

Output definition:

```
[OutputType(typeof(List<LinuxAlias>))]
```

LinuxAlias definition:

```
public class LinuxAlias
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String RawCommand { get; set; }

        public String Value { get; set; }
        public String TranslatedPowershellCommand { get; set; }
        public class COMMENT_BLOCK_EXCEPTION : Exception
        {
        }
        public class EMPTY_LINE_EXCEPTION : Exception
        {
        }
        public class UNRECOGNIZED_INPUT : Exception
        {
        }
    }
```

I do:

```
if ( Get-Module "MyModule" ) {
    Get-LinuxAliases | ForEach-Object -Process { 
        try {
            [string]$name = $_.Name;
            [string]$val = $_.Value;
                Set-Alias -Name $name -Value $val -Force;
        }
        catch {
            Write-Warning $_.Exception.GetType().FullName;
        }

    }
}
```

What is the expected behaviour? Since I noticed, for example. 
If I just `Write-Host $_.Name` and Write-Host $_.Value for each iteration. 
It first will write names and then values, having something like:

name1
name2
...
value1
value2
...

What is not the expected behaviour in a For-Each iterator I guess. 
It should be:

name1 value1 name2 value2

(Get-LinuxAliases) [0] returned :

```
Name RawCommand Value TranslatedPowershellCommand
---- ---------- ----- ---------------------------
cls  'clear'    clear
```

Someone could bring me light to this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For me it looks like `Get-LinuxAliases` is outpouting first LinuxAlias objects with only names and then LinuxAlias objects with only values.

Comment: try `(Get-LinuxAliases)[0]`

Comment: I m going to try. What you say have sense. I add more info to the post.

Comment: I Added (Get-LinuxAliases)[0] response to the post. Thanks for the help @T-Me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> that returns a List of LinuxAlias.

Generally, except in special circumstances, **cmdlets**:

- *should not* output *instances of a collection type* (such as `List` in your case).
- instead **should output *multiple* objects to the pipeline *one by one***.

The reason is that **other cmdlets - such as `ForEach-Object` - expect other commands to produce output *object by object***.

> `Get-LinuxAliases | ForEach-Object -Process { ...`

With your current design, `ForEach-Object` receives a *single* input object that is the *list as a whole*, which is not your intent.

Therefore:

- **Make your cmdlet-implementing class indicate that it returns `LinuxAlias`**, not a *list* of it; that *multiple* instances of that type may be returned is *invariably implied* in PowerShell.

  ```
  [OutputType(typeof(LinuxAlias)]
  ```
- To produce output from your cmdlet, **use `WriteObject(list, true)`, i.e., use the [`WriteObject` overload that *enumerates* collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.writeobject#System_Management_Automation_Cmdlet_WriteObject_System_Object_System_Boolean_)**; that is, make it send the `LinuxAlias` instances stored in your `List` instance to the pipeline *one by one*.